# ]In Revit ,With RevitNet.dll , Ray Intersect With LinkInstance , will get two difference result

Tags: revit-api

i want to find what hight data whith three pipe and more type flooe .
when i use ReferenceIntersector with RevitNet.dll . i set one point , the function will set two result , but the context element is one , the peoximity has two result.

this is my code :

```
 var intersector = new ReferenceIntersector(classFilter, FindReferenceTarget.Element, modelView);
                intersector.FindReferencesInRevitLinks = true;

                var result = intersector.Find(origin, -XYZ.BasisZ);

                foreach (var context in result)
                {
                    var ele = context.GetReference();
                    var revitLinkInstance = _document.GetElement(ele) as RevitLinkInstance;
                    var linkDoc = revitLinkInstance.GetLinkDocument();
                    
                    var eleName = linkDoc.GetElement(ele.LinkedElementId);
                    
                    var eleNmae = _document.GetElement(ele).Name;
            
                    
                    MessageBox.Show(result.Count.ToString() + "-" + eleNmae + $"{eleName.GetType()}" + "-" + context.Proximity * 304.8);
                }
```

this is my model:

[image]

the result will set two result :
[image]

how to distinguish between two values???